# VSTS - can I use a file publish via publish profile on a hosted agent?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a publish profile defined in my web project, but im using a hosted build agent.  For the release and deploy, can I publish to something other than a zip folder, then have the release agent (on-prem) copy files to the destination server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In my example, I've published all the files that I need to path `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` in my **build** definition (using a hosted build agent):

[image]

Then, in my **release** definition, I copied the files from `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` to my target server with private build agent:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I needed.  Will try this today.

Comment: I think its my build task that is failing.  I have a web project that I want to build that is within a solution with other projects.  I keep getting an error mentioning that I dont have a target matching the name of my project.  In the build task, Im using /t:project-name-here:debug

Comment: Ive tried setting this up.  The build goes fine, except there is nothing in the build artifacts.  See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471389/vsts-publish-artifact-empty-mvc-web-app-deploy-on-prem