# VSTS Publish Artifact empty, MVC web app deploy on-prem

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to use a hosted build agent and an on-prem release agent.
Project is an ASP.Net MVC web app within a solution with other projects.
The build completes successful but there is nothing in the artifact folder so the release does nothing.

[ update 5/22/2018]
What I need to do is publish to some location relevant to the hosted agent, then in my on-prem release agent, be able to use a copy_files task to simply copy those files to a unc path.

[ update  5/23/2018] 
Using these msbuild arguments on the build task, I was able to get a zipped folder containing the published files.  The only problem now is that the files are in a deeply nested structure.  So I either just need to unzip them on a release task, or prevent them from being zipped.

```
/t:My_MVCWeb_Project_Name /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Build log
[image]

Build task (Hosted VS 2017 agent).   The /t parameter is followed by a project_name.
[image]

Publish task of Build definition
[image]

Release definition, with just a copyfiles task (this runs on-prem)
[image]

Comment: You redacted a very relevant part of the build task definition: The MSBuild arguments.

Comment: The only msbuild argument in the build task is the /t parameter and its followed by a project_name.  That part seems fine.  Its the 1st screenshot that shows that the drop artifact is empty.  Ive updated the post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the default `MSBuild Arguments` in `Build` step since you use `ASP.NET build template`:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Or you need to add a [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) task before `Publish Build Artifacts`
 to copy the files you need to path `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`:

[image]

Comment: I put in a copy files task with the settings above, but when I get to the publish artifacts task I still see the message about nothing being added to the build artifact.  eg.  2018-05-23T13:22:09.9376904Z ##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Comment: If I use an msbuild command locally like this:  msbuild my_solution_name  /t:project_name, where project_name is the web project, I dont see a bin folder produce, but rather an obj folder, and under there is some folders that have the generated web files

Comment: I finally got it to work, almost.  See updates above.  I still need to change the msbuild parameters either on the build task or on the release tasks, add a step to unzip the files straight into the folder for the web app.